# Wsuggest-override raise warning even if override is present

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I'm currently trying to add all missing override to a project, so I use Wsuggest-override.

From the documentation :

> -Wsuggest-override
>
> Warn about overriding virtual functions that are not marked with the override >keyword.

However, it raises a warning for all function that should use the override keyword **even if the keyword is actually there**

From the log:

```
In file included from LdBitFieldProperty.cpp:16:0:
LdBitFieldProperty.h:47:29: warning: ‘virtual std::__cxx11::string LdBitFieldProperty::GetStringValue(size_t) const’ can be marked override [-Wsuggest-override]
         virtual std::string GetStringValue( size_t aIndex = 0 ) const override;
```

Am I missing something about this warning usage?

my gcc is : `gcc version 6.4.1 20170727 (Red Hat 6.4.1-1) (GCC)`

Comment: Could be triggered by the fact that function has 'virtual' keyword specified Can you try removing it and see if the warning is still there?

Comment: I've used [Clang-Tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) to do a similar thing in the past. It does a pretty good job of it IMHO.

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @SergeyA I'm going to annoy everyone by saying that I like keeping the `virtual` even when it's redundant. :P It's easier to spot virtual functions when I can consistently look at the preamble, rather than having to look after the argument list for only some of them.

Comment: I don't get any warning with a minimal scenario: `struct A { virtual void f() = 0;};
struct B : A { void f() override;};`

Comment: @GuillaumeGris Nor me, including if I add the redundant `virtual` in the derived class, with `g++.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 7.2.0`

Comment: @SergeyA same behaviour without virtual keyword. I'll update soon with a minimal example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all, it was a stupid problem, there was a `#define override` to remove override keyword because the project used to be c++99 compatible for linux platform.

Removal of the define fixed the problem.